# SurveyMonkey API v3 survey list - example wrong and list unhelpfully brief

Tags: surveymonkey

I am just starting converting an existing app from SurveyMonkey v2 API to v3.

I found the example response on the developer website for getting a survey list was incorrect - when I get a survey list it just contains ID, Title and URL for each survey.  It would be good if that could be corrected for the benefit of others.

My app needs the survey list so that it can present the user with a list of the surveys they have access to, and my current version shows date_modified, number of responses and number of questions.
All of this information was available in a single call in v2 API but in v3 we seem to have to go on to do a call for each survey individually in order to get the date_modified and number of questions information and a further call to get the number of responses.
Thus the v3 API is much less efficient at giving us what we need than v2 was.
Is it possible that the V3 survey list could be enhanced to contain that additional information?

Answer (score 1):

The docs need to be updated.

/v3/surveys?api_key=API_KEY&include=response_count,date_created,date_modified,language,question_count,analyze_url,preview
/v3/surveys/SURVEY_ID/collectors?api_key=API_KEY&include=type,status,response_count,date_created,date_modified,url

Comment: Thank you.
The documentation gives a completely different idea of what the include parameter is; I would never have guessed from there.

Comment: While I'm here, the documentation does not make it clear that the protocol for getting information has changed from a POST of JSON data in v2 to a GET with URL parameters in V3.  It took hours of experimenting to get it right.  An example in the documentation would be really helpful.